# Hitting issue with Joomla 4

Tags: joomla

I have several sites using Civicrm, one of which is a new Joomla4 website. CiviCRM is running smoothly but I have run into 2 issues.

The big issue is ACL permissions in Joomla. I am able access ACL for all installed components, however, when I go to CiviCRM in the Joomla ACL, I get the following message:

0 Failed opening required '/home/username/public_html/libraries/joomla/form/fields/rules.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/usr/share/pear')

When checking, the libraries/joomla folder does not exist. It exists in Joomla 3 and upon setting up a Joomla 4 test site, the directory doesn't exists.

This seems to be a joomla issue that is specific to CiviCRM so I wanted to ask here if anyone had thoughts on how to proceed. Obviously I need access to Joomla ACLs with CiviCRM.

Comment: I didn't see it before but I've located an open issue for this:
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues/35

Answer (score 2):

Until the fix is integrated into the master branch, to repair this issue, you'll need to apply the patch located at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-joomla/pull/67

To do so:

```
cd [Joomla root]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/joomla
wget https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-joomla/pull/67.patch
git apply --stat 67.patch
git apply --check 67.patch
git apply 67.patch
```

NOTE: When you run the "stat" the response should look like this:

```
 libraries/joomla/form/fields/civiperms.php |  132 +++++++++++++++++-----------
 1 file changed, 82 insertions(+), 50 deletions(-)
```

When you run "check" there should be no errors spit out.  Assuming no errors, then go ahead and run the patch with the apply command.

Labu apetīti!

P.S.: I applied this exact procedure to my own site and it worked as I expected.